# Sorted Lists not working properly in python

Tags: python, sortedlist

I'm sorting a csv file with 14 titles and 500,000 records in it. I organized them using the enumerate function. However, when I use the sorted() function to sort them using a key value (ex:total profit), it only returns numbers under 100,000 (ie. 99,992.36, when in reality some values go into the millions).

When I switch to a different key value (ex:total cost), I run into the same issue, however if that specific record happened to have a total profit over 100,000, that value does show. So I think I've narrowed it down to my sorted() function.

```
def processStats(originalList, header):

    #sorting in descending order
    sortedListByTotalProfit = sorted(originalList, key = operator.itemgetter(11), reverse = True)

    max_item = sortedListByTotalProfit[0]
    print(max_intem)

def main():
    fileName = 'Records.csv'
    records = []
    recordHeader = []    

    with open(fileName) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for i, line in enumerate(lines):
            if i == 0: #first line is the header, store it in the list by splitting the first record by comma
                recordHeader=line.split(',') 
                continue
            records.append(line.split(",")) #takes each record in the file and stores elements separated by commas as elements of a list

    processStats(records, recordHeader)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the data type is string.
You can use
`records.append(list(map(int, line.split(","))))` to replace `records.append(line.split(","))`
all code:

```py
def processStats(originalList, header):

    #sorting in descending order
    sortedListByTotalProfit = sorted(originalList, key = operator.itemgetter(11), reverse = True)

    max_item = sortedListByTotalProfit[0]
    print(max_intem)

def main():
    fileName = 'Records.csv'
    records = []
    recordHeader = []    

    with open(fileName) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for i, line in enumerate(lines):
            if i == 0: #first line is the header, store it in the list by splitting the first record by comma
                recordHeader=line.split(',') 
                continue
            records.append(records.append(list(map(int, line.split(","))))) #takes each record in the file and stores elements separated by commas as elements of a list

    processStats(records, recordHeader)
```